# Prove this inequality: $E[f(A^{(p)})+f(B^{(p)})]≥(1-p)(1-q)f(\emptyset)+p(1-q)f(A)+q(1-p)f(B)+pqf(A\cup B)$

Tags: probability, functions

Suppose f is a submodular function, which is a $2^\Omega\to R$ function, and for all $S,T\subset\Omega$, $f(S)+f(T)≥f(S\cup T)+f(S\cap T)$

For $0≤p≤1$ and set S, let $S^{(p)}$ be the random subset obtained by including each element in S independently with probability p.

Prove this inequality: $E[f(A^{(p)})+f(B^{(p)})]≥(1-p)(1-q)f(\emptyset)+p(1-q)f(A)+q(1-p)f(B)+pqf(A\cup B)$

Hint: first prove this, $E[f(A^{(p)})]≥(1-p)f(\emptyset)+pf(A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~feige/mypapers/FeigeMirrokniVondrak.pdf

I have found solution in this paper P4~5